# Converting wide to long format in sql server and dataframe has around 1000 columns - Optimize

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have dataframe df in wide format and has around 1000 columns. I need to convert this to long format

Sample table:

```
 Date   TLRA_Equity  KAMN_Equity  B_Equity  ARNC_Equity RC_Equity DAR_Equity
1/1/2000  10              20        30          40        50          60
2/1/2000  15              25        35          45        55          65
3/1/2000  17              27        37          47        57          67
```

I can convert this to long format by dataframe melt and insert to table in python with below code

```
        df = df.melt(id_vars = 'Date')
        query = "insert into table values (?,?,?)"
        cursor.executemany(query, df.values.tolist())
```

Data in long format:

```
  investment        variable      value  
 1/1/2000      TLRA_Equity       10    
 1/1/2000      KAMN_Equity       20    
 1/1/2000      B_Equity          30 
 1/1/2000      ARNC_Equity       40
```

But after converting long format it takes long time to update to table. Is there any way to insert into database table in wide format and covert it long format in sql to speed up the process.

Output by running 'John Cappelletti' solution

```
   Date         Item          Value
   1/1/2000     Date           1/1/2000
   1/1/2000     TLRA_x0020_Equity   10
   1/1/2000     KAMN_x0020_Equity   20
   1/1/2000     B_x0020_Equity      30
   1/1/2000     ARNC_x0020_Equity   40
```

Comment: There isn't a concept of long and short format. What you have at the top is denormalized and you are normalizing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly Unpivot would be more performant, but here is a approach that will "dynamically" unpivot your data without having to use dynamic SQL.

**The plus side** is that you won't have to specify 1000 columns.

**Example**

```
Select A.Date
      ,C.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                 Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Date')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

[image]

**EDIT**

```
 ...
,Item  = replace(xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)'),'_x0020_',' ')
 ...
```

Comment: I am getting different output. Can you please check what mistake i am doing? Output updated in the question.

Comment: @ArvinthKumar Do you have spaces in the column names?   If so XML will replace the space with x0020

Comment: Great, Its working fine. Thanks a lot for your help!!