# SQL For loop to find null, not null, total values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the number of null values, non-null values, total rows for each column in a table named `StudentScore`.

**Code to create table:**

```
CREATE TABLE StudentScore
    ( Student_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
      Student_Name NVARCHAR (50),
      Student_Score INT  ) 
    GO  INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (1,'Ali', NULL)
    INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (2,'Zaid', 770)
    INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (3,'Mohd', 1140)
    INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (4,NULL, 770)
    INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (5,'John', 1240)
    INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (6,'Mike', 1140)
    INSERT INTO StudentScore VALUES (7,'Goerge', NULL)
```

**Code to find number of null, non null, total rows for each column in the table:**

```
DECLARE @var varchar(max)
BEGIN
FOR @var in ----- to ---- LOOP
SELECT number of rows of each column, null values and non null values 

END LOOP
```

**Output expected**

```
 Column name    Total_Number_of_values    Number_of_non_null_values   No_of_Non_null_values
```

I have seen few answers but I am unable to understand the syntax...I want to implement this using for loop. How is this possible

I know that

```
   Total_Number_of_values    = Select COUNT(*) from StudentScore
   Number_of_non_null_values   = Select COUNT(My_col_name) from StudentScore
   No_of_Non_null_values= Select COUNT(*) - COUNT(My_col_name) from StudentScore
```

and I know that i can manipulate `Information_schema.columns`. But how to run a loop and do it for all columns in one go.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61426544/find-the-non-null-columns-in-sql-server-in-a-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is not paramount, here is a little item I've used in my discovery phase.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (Col1 varchar(100),Col2 varchar(100),Col3 varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('2018-05-23','Another Value',25.57)
,('2018-06-30','John Smith',3635.567595)
,('2018-07-01','Jane Doe',null)


;with cte as (
Select C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select ColNr  = Row_Number() over (Order by (select null))
                      ,Item   = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value  = a.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
             ) C
)
Select ColNr       = max(ColNr)
      ,Item 
      ,CntValues   = sum(1) 
      ,MinStrValue = min(Value)
      ,MaxStrValue = max(Value)
      ,MinStrLen   = min(len(Value))
      ,MaxStrLen   = max(len(Value))
      ,PctNumeric  = sum(IIF(try_convert(money,Value) is null,0,1)) / sum(convert(money,1))
      ,MinNumeric  = min(try_convert(money,Value))
      ,MaxNumeric  = max(try_convert(money,Value))
      ,MaxDecimal  = max(case when try_convert(money,Value) is not null and charindex('.',Value)>0 then len(parsename(Value,1)) else 0 end)
      ,PctDate     = sum(IIF(try_convert(date,Value) is null,0,1)) / sum(convert(money,1))
      ,MinDateTime = min(try_convert(datetime,Value))
      ,MaxDateTime = max(try_convert(datetime,Value))
 From  cte
 Group By Item
 Order By 1
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Nice one, The similar pattern with XML/JSON could be used for performing unpivot :) Thank you for sharing.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Thanks for the grin  :)  and yes there is a JSON version which is a nudge faster.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Here is a dynamic unpivot without Dynamic SQL  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55424546/converting-wide-to-long-format-in-sql-server-and-dataframe-has-around-1000-colum/55424679#55424679

Answer (score 1):

this creates a stacked output of your results, with no for loop required, 
with 1 row for each column

```
create table poo 
(
    a int,b int, c int
)

insert into poo (a,c) select 1,4
insert into poo (a,c) select 1,7
insert into poo (b,c) select 4,7
insert into poo (b) select 9
insert into poo (a) select 13
insert into poo (c) select 22

declare @l_s varchar(max)=''

select @l_s = @l_s+case when r > 1 then ' union all ' else '' end + s from
(
        select  'select '''+column_name+''' col
                      , sum(case when '+column_name+' is null then 1 else 0  end) nulls 
                      , sum(case when '+column_name+' is null then 0 else 1  end) not_nulls 
                      , count(*) c 
                      from ' +table_name+' ' s,
                    row_number() over (partition by table_name order by column_name) r
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name = 'poo'
) ilv

print(@l_s)
exec (@l_s)
```

for what its worth tsql has no for loop

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL does not have FOR syntax, however you can implement loop logics using [WHILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [CURSOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). You can use Cursor to achieve your goal as below:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#result') is not null
    drop table #result
create table #result (name varchar(max), TotalCount int, NullCount int, NonNullCount int)

declare C cursor fast_forward for(
select name from sys.columns where object_id = OBJECT_ID('StudentScore')
)
declare @name varchar(max)
open c
fetch next from c into @name
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
    declare @qry nvarchar(max)
    set @qry = '
        insert into #result
        Select '''+@name+''', * FROM(
        select 
            count(*) as TotalCount,
            count(case when '+@name+' is null then 1 else null end) as NullCount,
            count(case when '+@name+' is not null then 1 else null end) as NonNullCount
        from StudentScore
        ) as K
    '
    print @qry
    exec sp_executesql @qry, N'@name varchar(max)', @name
    fetch next from c into @name
end
close c
deallocate c

select * from #result
```